# Efficient creation of a array from a matrix in Malab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this matrix a N x 3 matrix, say A

A =

```
 2     3     9
 7     1     2
 5     4     7
14    15    13
13    10     9
 8     6     5
11     8    10
16    12    11
```

and i want to construct a 2N x 2 array, say b. This array have in rows 2, 3 and 9 the value 1, i.e A(1,:)=[2 3 9]. In rows 7, 1 and 2 have value 2, i.e A(2,:) = [ 7 1 2] and so on. The output must be,

b =

```
 2     0
 1     2
 1     0
 3     0
 3     6
 6     0
 2     3
 6     7
 1     5
 5     7
 7     8
 8     0
 4     5
 4     0
 4     0
 8     0
```

Comment: unclear question!

Comment: Is that `1` in both entries of a row? What should be in the remaining rows? Please edit your question to clarify. Consider showing a smaller matrix `A` with the expected output.

Comment: Let A(i,:) = [aa bb cc], then in rows aa, bb and cc of array b, we must put the index i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted:

```
A = [2     3     9;
 7     1     2;
 5     4     7;
14    15    13;
13    10     9;
 8     6     5;
11     8    10;
16    12    11];
[~,Aidxs1,~] = unique(A,'stable');
Aidxs2 = find(~ismember(1:numel(A),Aidxs1));
[row1,~] = ind2sub(size(A),Aidxs1);
[row2,~] = ind2sub(size(A),Aidxs2);
Bidxs1 = A(Aidxs1);
Bidxs2 = A(Aidxs2);
B = zeros(2*size(A,1),2);
B(Bidxs1,1) = row1;
B(Bidxs2,2) = row2;
```

and then you have:

```
B = [2     0
 1     2
 1     0
 3     0
 3     6
 6     0
 2     3
 6     7
 1     5
 5     7
 7     8
 8     0
 5     4
 4     0
 4     0
 8     0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `unique` function has an `occurrence flag` that can be set to `first` or `last` to find index to the first/last occurrence of the repeated value.
For the first column of `b` we need indices to rows  of the first occurrence and for the second column ,if there is a repeated value,we need indices to rows  of the second(last) occurrence.

```
% transpose A to find elemnts row-wise
[~,idx1] = unique(A.','first');
%convert linear index to row index
b(:,1) = ceil(idx1/size(A,2));

[~,idx2] = unique(A.','last');
% if there is a repeated value we need index of the last occurrence 
AC = accumarray(A(:),1)>1;
b(AC,2) = ceil(idx2(AC)/size(A,2));

b =
   2   0
   1   2
   1   0
   3   0
   3   6
   6   0
   2   3
   6   7
   1   5
   5   7
   7   8
   8   0
   4   5
   4   0
   4   0
   8   0
```